# Basic Template Engine Fix

Tags: php

I am attempting to make a (very) basic template engine for php. Based on my research I have found that a method that I am using is strongly disliked. I was wondering if anyone knew a great alternative to get the same result so I am not using it. And if anyone sees any other improvements that can be made please share!

the method that is not advised is the `eval()` method!

Here is the php file

```
<?php

class Engine {
    private $vars = array();

public function assign($key, $value) {
    $this->vars[$key] = $value;
}

public function render($file_name) {
    $path = $file_name . '.html';

    if (file_exists($path)) {

        $content = file_get_contents($path);

        foreach ($this->vars as $key => $value) {
            $content = preg_replace('/\{' . $key . '\}/', $value, $content);
        }

        eval(' ?>' . $content . '<?php ');

    } else {
        exit('<h4>Engine Error</h4>');
    }
  }
}

?>
```

here is the index.php file

```
<?php

include_once 'engine.php';

$engine = new Engine;

$engine->assign('username', 'Zach');
$engine->assign('age', 21);

$engine->render('test');

?>
```

and here is just a test html file to display its basic function

`My name is {username} and I am {age} years old!`

outputs:

`My name is Zach and I am 21 years old!`

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does anyone know what I can replace the `eval()` method with??????

Comment: Other templating systems use `include` - e.g. Twig does this with template files parsed and compiled to PHP classes. Just make sure your templates don't get compromised with malicious code.

Comment: @Lukas so your saying replace `eval()` with `include` im confused

Comment: No. I'm saying that including PHP code is common practice for tamplating engines. There's actually not much difference between `include xy.php;` and `eval(file_get_contents('xy.php'));` - only that the latter requires two steps.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to output some text to the page, just use `echo`:

```
echo $content;
```

This is better than `eval('?>' . $content . '<?php')` for quite a few reasons: for one, if someone types in `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, for example, as their username, it won't execute that code.

I would, however, note that you have some other problems. What if I do this?

```
$engine = new Engine;

$engine->assign('username', '{age}');
$engine->assign('age', 21);

$engine->render('test');
```

The `{age}` in the `username` value will be replaced with `21`. Usually you don't want replacements to be replaced like that, particularly as it's order-dependent (if you assigned `username` later, it wouldn't happen).

Comment: i read that using `eval()` allows for the use of php code and simply using `echo` does not. I want to replace `eval()` but still have the ability to use php

Comment: @zachstarnes: You mean you want to be able to have `<?php` blocks inside of the template, you want to be able to have `<?php` blocks inside of replaced values, or what?

Comment: right `echo` only allows for text or html while `eval` allows the use of php.

Comment: @zachstarnes: I know that, but I'm saying where, specifically, do you want to allow `<?php` blocks? It's a security vulnerability to allow it everywhere, so you need to decide what places you want to allow it and what places you don't.

Comment: i apologize for misunderstanding you. I am not sure but if I were to want to include it how would I go about doing it?

Comment: @zachstarnes: It depends on where.